# Pointers and memory management in Python

Tags: python, pointers, memory, memory-management

I've started learning Python yesterday, and it seems to abstract away many features that would otherwise be essential for a language like C (which I know).

I understand the appeal of a much simpler syntax, short code and less memory-related bugs, but, in certain cases, I'd prefer to manually allocate, reallocate and free memory, as well as using pointers. Is there any way to do so in Python 3.10?

Comment: Possibly you could, but why? If you want to do everything yourself, why use a language that does everything for you?

Comment: Yes, there are techniques, but this is too vague.  SO is about solving problems.  Show a "certain case" where you need this.

Comment: @sj95126 I'm required to use Python, it's not by choice. Still, I'd like to learn Python, I'm not trying strip it down so it looks more like C, but it'd be nice to know I can manually do everything myself if I see fit.

Comment: @MarkTolonen say I want to implement hash tables and tries myself without using dictionaries. It's not all that useful for 'real life' problems, since I'd either use dictionaries or just use C instead, if I want to implement it myself, but as I stated in the previous comment, I'm required to use Python by my university. Would you mind pointint me to those techniques?

Comment: Google [hash table implementation Python](https://coderbook.com/@marcus/how-to-create-a-hash-table-from-scratch-in-python/). Also see the`ctypes` module. It’s intended to interface to C APIs, but you can use it for (slow) pointer analogs.